# Windows7: Timeout when uploading via FTP

Tags: windows-7, ftp, timeout

I'm having problems on Windows7 when uploading files via ftp to my webhoster e. g. by Filezilla. I've set the mode to "passive". When I try to upload a file the progress bar reaches 100% fastly, then everything hangs and after some time I get a message about a timeout:

> Status: Auflösen der IP-Adresse für ulrichbangert.de
>   Status: Verbinde mit 85.13.140.237:21...
>   Status: Verbindung hergestellt, warte auf Willkommensnachricht...
>   Status: Initialisiere TLS...
>   Status: Überprüfe Zertifikat...
>   Status: TLS-Verbindung hergestellt.
>   Status: Angemeldet
>   Status: Empfange Verzeichnisinhalt für "/"...
>   Status: Anzeigen des Verzeichnisinhalts für "/" abgeschlossen
>   Status: Empfange Verzeichnisinhalt für "/div"...
>   Status: Ungültige Zeichenfolge empfangen, UTF-8 wird deaktiviert. Wählen Sie UTF-8 im Servermanager, um UTF-8 zu erzwingen.
>   Status: Anzeigen des Verzeichnisinhalts für "/div" abgeschlossen
>   Status: Empfange Verzeichnisinhalt für "/div/testftp"...
>   Status: Anzeigen des Verzeichnisinhalts für "/div/testftp" abgeschlossen
>   Status: Auflösen der IP-Adresse für ulrichbangert.de
>   Status: Verbinde mit 85.13.140.237:21...
>   Status: Verbindung hergestellt, warte auf Willkommensnachricht...
>   Status: Initialisiere TLS...
>   Status: Überprüfe Zertifikat...
>   Status: TLS-Verbindung hergestellt.
>   Status: Angemeldet
>   Status: Starte Upload von D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\test4.html
>   Befehl: CWD /div/testftp
>   Antwort: 250 CWD command successful
>   Befehl: PWD
>   Antwort: 257 "/div/testftp" is the current directory
>   Befehl: TYPE A
>   Antwort: 200 Type set to A
>   Befehl: PASV
>   Antwort: 227 Entering Passive Mode (85,13,140,237,195,174).
>   Befehl: STOR test4.html
>   Antwort: 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for test4.html
>   Fehler: Zeitüberschreitung der Verbindung nach 20 Sekunden Inaktivität
>   Fehler: Dateiübertragung fehlgeschlagen

The last lines translate:
"Error: Timeout of connection after 20 sec inacitivity"
"Error: Transmission of file failed"
Other FTP clients encounter the same errror.
When I use my smartphone and transfer files via the same WLAN to the same server everything works fine. Thus the problem seems to be located on my local PC. Switching off firewall (windows7) and antivirus software didn't remove the problem.
I tried using the command line FTP and there everything works fine. I learned that the command line FTP uses active mode. Therefore I tried to set Filezilla to active too but then I do not get the directory listing after connection:

> Status:   Auflösen der IP-Adresse für ulrichbangert.de Status:    Verbinde
>   mit 85.13.140.237:21... Status:   Verbindung hergestellt, warte auf
>   Willkommensnachricht... Status:   Initialisiere TLS... Status:    Überprüfe
>   Zertifikat... Status: TLS-Verbindung hergestellt. Status: Angemeldet
>   Status:   Empfange Verzeichnisinhalt für "/"... Befehl:   CWD /
>   Antwort:  250 CWD command successful Befehl:  TYPE I Antwort: 200 Type
>   set to I Befehl:  PORT 192,168,1,100,196,2 Antwort:   200 PORT command
>   successful Befehl:    MLSD Fehler:    Zeitüberschreitung der Verbindung nach
>   20 Sekunden Inaktivität Fehler:   Verzeichnisinhalt konnte nicht
>   empfangen werden

The last lines translate:
"Error: Timeout of connection after 20 sec of inactivity"
"Error: Content of directory could not be received"

I'm helpless and search for support. Threads at stackoverflow and https://www.windows-7-forum.net provided no solution.

Best regards - Ulrich

Comment: Does the FTP client on your smartphone use TLS (encryption)? Command-line `ftp` does not. Did you try to turn off encryption in FileZilla? If this does not help, we need to see: 1) English logs of FileZilla (switch FileZilla to English, do not try to translate the logs on your own), 2) Output of command-line `ftp.exe`. 3) If possible, some logs/output of the FTP client on your smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Listing was too long for a comment.

@Martin Prikryl Passive mode, plain FTP without encryption (insecure): Some files work, zahlenschloss times out for the first transfer, then succeeds.

> Status:   Starting upload of
>   D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\youtube-api-playlist-2.html
>   Status:   Disconnected from server Status:    Resolving address of
>   ulrichbangert.de Status:  Connecting to 85.13.140.237:21...
>   Status:   Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>   Status:   Logged in Status:   Starting upload of
>   D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\youtube-api-playlist-3.html Status:    File
>   transfer successful, transferred 1.409 bytes in 1 second Status:  File
>   transfer successful, transferred 1.886 bytes in 1 second
>   Status:   Starting upload of D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\youtube-api.html
>   Status:   Starting upload of
>   D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\youtube-api-playlist.html Status:  File
>   transfer successful, transferred 1.489 bytes in 1 second
>   Status:   Starting upload of
>   D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\zahlenschloss.html Status: File transfer
>   successful, transferred 1.160 bytes in 1 second Status:   Starting
>   upload of D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\zahlenschloss2.html Status:  File
>   transfer successful, transferred 7.994 bytes in 1 second
>   Status:   Starting upload of
>   D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\zahlenschloss3.html Status:    File transfer
>   successful, transferred 7.947 bytes in 1 second Status:   Starting
>   upload of D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\zahlenschloss4.html Status:  File
>   transfer successful, transferred 9.984 bytes in 9 seconds
>   Status:   Starting upload of D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\zoomdiv.html
>   Status:   File transfer successful, transferred 8.296 bytes in 1 second
>   Status:   Starting upload of
>   D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\zufallszahl-slots.html Status: File
>   transfer successful, transferred 4.646 bytes in 1 second Command: PASV
>   Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (85,13,140,237,196,45).
>   Command:  STOR zahlenschloss.html Response:   150 Opening ASCII mode data
>   connection for zahlenschloss.html Error:  Connection timed out after 20
>   seconds of inactivity Error:  File transfer failed Status:    Starting
>   upload of D:\temp_Webprogrammierung\zahlenschloss.html
>   Status:   Retrieving directory listing of "/div/testftp"... Status:   File
>   transfer successful, transferred 10.135 bytes in 1 second
>   Status:   Retrieving directory listing of "/div/testftp"...
>   Status:   Directory listing of "/div/testftp" successful

Active mode works now.

Smartphone: AndFTP, Type: SCP, passive mode, SSH key: optional, key: optional

Comment: Correction: Active mode does **not** work.